# Editing in QGIS vertex tool

Tags: qgis, editing, vertices

By opening a multipolygon shape file, and enabling Vertex Tool (under Edit->Edit geometry) am able to see the X, Y coordinates of the points making the polygon. When i use Vector->Geometry Tools->Extract Vertices (on a temporary layer), the vertices are defined as distance/angle - it's unclear what is considered to be the root node of these distance/angle data.
Anyone with an idea on how I can locate this root reference in by data?

Comment: Probably layer units from the origin (coord 0/0) of the layer's CRS?

Answer (score 1):

Below the help text from the "Extract vertices" tool :

> This algorithm takes a line or polygon layer and generates a point
> layer with points representing the vertices in the input lines or
> polygons. The attributes associated to each point are the same ones
> associated to the line or polygon that the point belongs to.
>
> Additional fields are added to the point indicating the vertex index
> (beginning at 0), the vertex’s part and its index within the part (as
> well as its ring for polygons), distance along original geometry and
> bisector angle of vertex for original geometry.

Reading from that the distance/angle you get are `distance along original geometry` and `bisector angle of vertex for original geometry`.

If you want the x and y coordinate of the vertex you need to use the "Add X/Y fields to layer" tool on the layer resulting of the "Extract vertices" tool